# Is it possible to use Androids GoogleMap in a background service?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to generate thumbnails of different maps so they can be displayed in a list, which gives an overview over all available maps in my App. 
For the generation of a map screenshot I found the [snapshot](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#snapshot(com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback))-method in GoogleMap.

Now I would like to run the thumbnail Generation in a background thread.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html) you need to call `getMap`on a `MapView`or a `MapFragment` to instantiate a GoogleMap.

Is there a different way of getting hold of a GoogleMap-Object, instead of using the View or the Fragment? Is there something like a OffScreenRenderer that would allow to use the GoogleMap without actually displaying it on the Screen and ideally running it not in the MainThread?

Answer (score 0):

1. For thumbnails I use [Static Maps API V2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) and [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).
2. But you want to show those list thumbnails some time in the future, right? If yes then generate them when showing (and cache after showing).

Comment: sound like a good alternative, but nevertheless I would like to do it without sending queries to a server.

Comment: so go with 2nd poposal - build thumbnail when showing them in main thread and then cache them; showing map is indeed a kind of query to server (google server which servers map tiles) anyway